# Apache 2 : Multiple Website sharing same domain

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

Currently I have set up an apache 2 webserver running on ubuntu 11.04, using passenger to serve rails apps. As such, I have multiple apps that is going to be run on that server.

I am only given 1 IP address (111.222.333.444) with no access to create CNAME on my own for subdomains.

**Problem :**

Is there a way to configure apache2 the multiple apps can be access in this manner :

111.222.3333.4444/app1 => This will direct to app1
111.222.3333.4444/app2 => This will direct to app2
111.222.3333.4444/app3 => This will direct to app3

Thanks people!

Answer (score -1):

you could use apache vhost to point to each app either by domain name or port number

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html